# When does $R/I$ act transitively on $M$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative local ring and $M$ be a $R$ module, i.e., $R$ is acting on $M$. Let $I$ be a  prime ideal of $R$.

Assume that the action of $R$ on $M$ factors through the quotient $R/I$.

$(1)$ When does $R/I$ act transitively on $M$ ?

$(2)$ When $M$ (as $R$-module) is generated by a single generator ?

or When $M$ is principally generated a $R$-module ?

$$-------$$

I need something like: $M=R \cdot x$ for some $x \in M$. Such situation happens when $M$ is cyclic module or when $R$ act transitively (so single orbit) on $M$.

Any discussion please.

Comment: what does it mean to say that a ring acts transitively on a module? note that orbits in the sense we use them for group actions are not well-defined in a module, since it is possible to have $m,n\in M$ such that $n\in Rm$ but $m\notin Rn$. indeed, we have $0\in Rm$ for all $m\in M$, but never have $m\in R0$ for any $m\neq 0$.

Comment: in particular, if we want the definition of transitive to be "for all $m,n\in M$, there exists $r\in R$ such that $rm=n$", then this will never be possible unless $M=\{0\}$

Comment: What I need is $R \cdot x=M$ for a fixed $x \in M$. This is possible when $M$ is cyclic module. Is there other situations making it possible except cyclic case ?

Comment: dear Mathlearner, in fact, that is one way of *defining* of a cyclic module :) ... ie we say that an $R$-module $M$ is cyclic if there exists some $x\in M$ such that $R\cdot x=M$. (but note that you will not be able to choose an arbitrary $x$ –– for instance, if $M\neq\{0\}$, then we will *never* have $R\cdot x=M$ when $x=0$.)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, thanks

Comment: my pleasure, happy it helped! :)